# Get date in dd/mm/yyyy format instead of mm/dd/yyyyy from Date time Picker and Textbox C#

Tags: c#, sql-server, datetime

Im trying Get date in dd/mm/yyyy format instead of mm/dd/yyyyy format from Date time Picker and Textbox C# but Im facing "String was not recognized as valid Date Time" message error"

I tried this code

```
if (tb_date.Text == "")
{
    tb_date.Text = dtp_addingDebit.Value.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy");
}
else
{
    tb_date.Text = Convert.ToDateTime(tb_date.Text).ToString("dd/MM/yyyy");
}
```

Im using the result of If condition with insert stored procedure

```
AddingDebit_con.AddingNewDebit(int.Parse(combo_customers.SelectedValue.ToString()),tb_date.Text, Convert.ToInt32(tb_amount.Text));
```

**AddingDebit_con** is .cs file which contain the code below

```
public void InsertCustomer(string customer_fullname, string customer_phone, string customer_address, string customer_date)
{
    DAL.DataAccessLayer DAL = new DAL.DataAccessLayer();
    DAL.Open();
    SqlParameter[] param = new SqlParameter[4];
    param[0] = new SqlParameter("@customer_fullname", SqlDbType.NVarChar); param[0].Value = customer_fullname;
    param[1] = new SqlParameter("@customer_phone", SqlDbType.NVarChar); param[1].Value = customer_phone;
    param[2] = new SqlParameter("@customer_address", SqlDbType.NVarChar); param[2].Value = customer_address;
    param[3] = new SqlParameter("@customer_date", SqlDbType.Date); param[3].Value = customer_date;
    DAL.ExcuteCommand("Inserting_Customers", param);
    DAL.Close();
}
```

and **AddingNewDebit** is stored procedure which contain the Sql-server code below

```
ALTER proc [dbo].[Inserting_Customers]

@customer_fullname nvarchar(max),
@customer_phone nvarchar(max),
@customer_address nvarchar(max),
@customer_date date
AS
INSERT INTO Customers
           ([customer_fullname]
           ,[customer_phone]
           ,[customer_address]
           ,[customer_date]
           )
     VALUES
           (@customer_fullname,
           @customer_phone, 
           @customer_address ,
           @customer_date
          )
```

Comment: Why do you have `customer_date` as `string`? `... string customer_date ...`?

Comment: it was my 1st mistake thanks for your help

Comment: Just as  an FYI, define your parameter data types *properly* There is *no way* a customer's phone number is going to be over 4,000 characters, so why are you stating it is likely to be?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are trying to set `string` value as `DateTime`:

```
// Note "string" type for "customer_date"
public void InsertCustomer(... string customer_date)
{
    ...
    // MS SQL expects "DateTime" - SqlDbType.Date
    param[3] = new SqlParameter("@customer_date", SqlDbType.Date); 
    
    // But it's given "string"
    param[3].Value = customer_date;
    ...
}
```

I suggest changing `customer_date` type:

```
// customer_date is DateTime now
public void InsertCustomer(... DateTime customer_date) 
{
   ...
}
```

When you want to call the method you should provide `DateTime`:

```
// Note absence of any "ToString()" here
InsertCustomer(..., myDateTimePicker.Value);
```

Comment: thanks you for help :)   It works but the date format still inserted as mm/dd/yyyy how I can fix it and also i want the user be able to write date in dd/mm/yyyy format in textbox also

Comment: @Khayal Ads: please, note, that you can have *ambiguous values*: `11/5/2023` - is it `5 November 2023` or `11 May 2023`?

Comment: @Khayal Ads: if you want to get `DateTime`  from string use `TryParse`: `if (DateTime.TryParse(myText, out var myDate)) { /* valid myDate*/} else {/* invalid input */} `

Answer (score 0):

Ensure that control Format property is properly set to use a custom format:

```
dtp_addingDebit.Format = dtp_addingDebit.Custom
```

Then this is how you can set your desired format:

```
dtp_addingDebit.CustomFormat = "dd-MM-yyyy"
```